# Logging in created a new account instead of associating existing account

Tags: support, bug, login, user-accounts, linked-accounts

Today I wanted to ask a question on Super User. It showed me that I'm not logged in so I clicked "log in". I first tried my e-mail and password, but it didn't work.

Next I tried to log in using my Google account. It worked, but I got a username like userXXXXXX, which is not my normal username (Barteks2x). So I deleted this account and thought I would try again with different email and password. But to my surprise there was no "log in" button any more.

There was only the "join" button. So I clicked it. It wanted me to log in with Google which didn't work. After half hour of trying to find some way to log in normally I decided to continue logging in with Google. When I logged in I saw that I can switch to my Stack Overflow account by clicking the "Stack Exchange" button on the top, so I thought everything was OK now, so I proceeded to ask this question: https://superuser.com/questions/1098915/copying-files-to-usb-3-0-external-hdd-connected-to-usb-3-0-hub-with-external-pow.

After I asked it I realized that I have the randomly generated username, so I thought I accidentally created new account instead of logging into existing account. So then (I know it was probably wrong thing to do) I edited my question to include a question what I can do about it. One comment said that I can delete this question and re-create it from original account. So I deleted the question, and deleted the account again.

Now I see that I can easily log into my Stack Overflow account, but whenever I try to join Super User I get this strange random username, which is apparently the same account that I already deleted twice.

What is going on? How can I fix the mess?

Comment: You most likely used two different emails or OpenID providers. You shouldn't bother with it at all, when logged in to Stack Overflow you should see "Join this community" instead of "log in", in any other site you're not logged into yet, and you know for sure it's the same account as on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Anyway, you can let the new "random" account live, ask your question using it, then ask to merge it with your main account as explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist). All posts you made and votes you gained (or cast) will be preserved.

Comment: Now I'm replying from other computer, where I successfully logged into my normal account (and don't know how to log into that random account). I have no idea how can I log out of that weird account which behaves like 2 accounts at once. On communities I'm already in I'm "Barteks2x" but when I try to join new communities it uses the random account. And since the question is now deleted, I don't know what to do about it. Somehow undelete it? Ask it again from normal account?

Comment: @Barteks2x no point to bother too much, ask what you need with this account of yours, and make sure to use this computer when you want to use this account. If you'll need to switch computers again, like I said create the new account then ask for a merge, since you most likely forgot how you logged in three years ago. (or switched email provider since then)